# How to get related row from same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+---------+
| id | related |  color  |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | red     |
| 2  | 1       | blue    |
| 3  | 3       | green   |
| 4  | 1       | white   |
| 5  | 3       | brown   |
| 6  | 6       | gray    |
| 7  | 3       | black   |
| 8  | 1       | orange  |
| 9  | 6       | pink    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I have an `id` number and I need to get the color of related `id`.

For example:

```
$id = 4; // I need to get `red`
$id = 5; // I need to get `green`
$id = 6; // I need to get `gray`
$id = 9; // I need to get `gray`
```

I can do that by using a `JOIN`. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT t2.color FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.related = t2.id WHERE t1.id = :id
```

My query works as expected .. But I'm not sure using a `JOIN` for doing that is standard. Actually I'm trying to know is there any better approach? Or mine is a normal way?

Comment: Self join is perfectly fine!

Comment: @jarlh Yes I know, it is fine. But I want to know is it the best? I mean if you want to do that *(as an user with 15k rep)*, will you use a self-join? Or that approach is fine for me that I have only 1k rep?

Comment: I'd do the same self join as you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with `SELECT t.related FROM mytable t WHERE t.id = :id`? JOIN makes nothing more but checking if there is a actual id in 'related' column or not

Comment: This condition `t.related = :id` on `WHERE` clause is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for a misspelling, fixed it

Comment: Still that condition is wrong. Take a look at those examples on the question.

Comment: Your query would be correct. Upvote. But I've edited my table structure, what's your opinion about it? I need to get `color`

Comment: In such case joining a table to itself is absolutely normal. May be It's a bit easier to think about each joined table "instance" as a separated copy of original table filtered by certain list of conditions

Answer (score 2):

I've done two different query and explain them, hope can give you some hints.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2bb1/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (`id` int, `related` int, `color` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    (`id`, `related`, `color`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'red'),
    (2, 1, 'blue'),
    (3, 3, 'green'),
    (4, 1, 'white'),
    (5, 3, 'brown'),
    (6, 6, 'gray'),
    (7, 3, 'black'),
    (8, 1, 'orange'),
    (9, 6, 'pink')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t2.color FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.related = t2.id WHERE t1.id = '4'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2bb1/3/0)**:

```
| color |
|-------|
|   red |
```

**Query 2**:

```
explain SELECT t2.color FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.related = t2.id WHERE t1.id = '4'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2bb1/3/1)**:

```
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys |    key | key_len |    ref | rows |                                              Extra |
|----|-------------|-------|------|---------------|--------|---------|--------|------|----------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    t1 |  ALL |        (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) |    9 |                                        Using where |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    t2 |  ALL |        (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) |    9 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT t1.color FROM mytable t1 WHERE exists (select 1 from mytable t2 where t1.id =  t2.related and t2.id ='4')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2bb1/3/2)**:

```
| color |
|-------|
|   red |
```

**Query 4**:

```
explain SELECT t1.color FROM mytable t1 WHERE exists (select 1 from mytable t2 where t1.id =  t2.related and t2.id ='4')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2bb1/3/3)**:

```
| id |        select_type | table | type | possible_keys |    key | key_len |    ref | rows |       Extra |
|----|--------------------|-------|------|---------------|--------|---------|--------|------|-------------|
|  1 |            PRIMARY |    t1 |  ALL |        (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) |    9 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |    t2 |  ALL |        (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) |    9 | Using where |
```

Comment: Well played ..! upvote. Just I don't know understand the result of `EXPLAIN`. *query1* is better or *query3* ?

Comment: There isn't too much difference between these two query, maybe when you use index, there is some performance difference, and as you said, I'll prefer _query3_ as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this in simple ways also

```
select t.color from mytable t where t.id = '$id' (for one value)
select t.color from mytable t where t.id in ('$id1','$id2','$id3','$id4' ) (for multi-values comma separated strings)
```